# where does updateSearchResultsForSearchController get it's data from?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to understand how updateSearchResultsForSearchController works. I'm currently following examples from a book where it was not explained very well.

I have a table of data managed by ViewController.swift and another file, SearchResultsController.swift, to manage search results within that table.

Data comes from a dictionary in **ViewController.swift**:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
        var searchController: UISearchController!
        var names: [String: [String]]!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            names = ["A": ["Abe", "Anna"], "B":["Bob"]]     

            let resultsController = SearchResultsController()
            resultsController.names = names
            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)

            let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
            searchBar.sizeToFit()
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
        }
    }
```

Implementation for the **SearchResultsController.swift** is something like:

```
class SearchResultsController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var names:[String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()
    var filteredNames: [String] = []

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text
        filteredNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        if (!searchString.isEmpty) {
            let filter: String -> Bool = { name in

            let nameLength = countElements(randomVar)
            println("nameLength for name \(randomVar) is \(nameLength)")
        }
    }
}
```

checking the logs, I saw:

```
nameLength for name Abe is 3
nameLength for name Anna is 4
nameLength for name Bob is 3
```

1. How was it possible for SearchResultsController to see the data inside the dictionary **names**?
2. It would appear to be iterating over the array **names**. How did it happen that each element of the array was assigned to the variable **name** in this line of code in **SearchResultsController.swift**?

   let filter: String -> Bool = { name in